# Проблема с загрузкой картинки на сервер

Tags: android-sdk, android, php, post

вот функция которая отправляет POST запрос с файлом

```
public  JSONObject postFile(String fileName) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER);
    MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity =
MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    multipartEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(fileName)));
    post.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    // response.getStatusLine();  // CONSIDER  Detect server complaints
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String

    entity.consumeContent();
    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    return jObj;

}
```

а вот на приеме  php

```
if ($_FILES){
    $uploads_dir = 'uploads/';
    $uploadname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir.$uploadname);
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

почему-то картинка не загружается. Не знаю в чем именно проблема. но ответ от POST пишет мне "success 1" то есть php файл оно находит и даже выполняет, но файл не появляется на хостинге

сделал как посоветовали

```
if ($_FILES){
    $uploads_dir = 'uploads/';
    $uploadname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir.$uploadname))
    $response["success"] = 1;
else
    $response["success"] = 0;
echo json_encode($response);
     file_put_contents("log.txt",serialize($_FILES));
}
```

появился лог файл

```
a:1:{s:4:"file";a:5:{s:4:"name";s:12:"IMAG0284.jpg";s:4:"type";s:24:"application/octet-stream";s:8:"tmp_name";s:36:"/home/autost02/.system/tmp/phplsAIRP";s:5:"error";i:0;s:4:"size";i:623552;}}
```

**я почему-то больше не могу добавлять комменты под ответом. пишу здесь:
а как выполнить команду записи файла на пхп как администратор, имея все права? Создал папку upload, но все равно файл не отправляется.**

Comment: не нужно от администратор. На сервер пишется все от того имени, на которое настроен сервер. 1) поставьте на папку права 777 для начала, чтобы наверняка. 2)поставьте полный путь $uploads_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/'; 3) и наиболее важный и правильный - включите отображение ошибок и посмотрите что за ошибка )))

Comment: уже нашел решение, нужно было в пути после точки поставить пробел, хотя не понимаю, почему из-за этого заработало. все равно спасибо за помощь, вы помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас в любом случае будет успех, т.к. нет проверки на move_uploaded_file

Сделайте

```
$uploads_dir = 'uploads/';
$uploadname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir.$uploadname));
    $response["success"] = 1;
else
    $response["success"] = 0;
echo json_encode($response);
```

и теперь, возможно, не будет уже успешным.

Добавьте проверку того что у вас вообще в $_FILES

```
 $response["file"] = $_FILES;
```

или

```
 file_put_contents("log.txt",serialize($_FILES));
```

и посмотрите, доходит ли файл и если доходит, какая структура

Comment: файл log.txt не появился. succes "0"

Comment: Потому что в Андроиде не всегда файл отправится POST запросом. Мне для реализации загрузки фото в Вконтакте пришлось открывать output stream и писать картинку по байтам, а в конце писать символы окончания HTTP запроса.

Comment: а как понять "не всегда"? а когда отправится. ну вконтакте само собой, там авторизация жесткая и свой набор правил. а я просто хочу залить на хостинг картинку

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, а можно вашу реализацию через output stream на почту jenyakirmiza@gmail.com, либо сюда бросьте.

Comment: @Firespirit, у меня схожая реализация с Вашей и отправляется. Но вижу что в логе появилось. Значит на стороне андроида уже все хорошо. Теперь нужно понять почему не сохранилось в PHP. Может права на папку не подходят?

Comment: @aldem67, вот об этом я в первую очередь и подумал. дело в том, что я только пару месяцев назад начал заниматься разработкой, а php вообще не изучал, взял просто скопипастил куски кода и подстроил их под свои нужды, так же я поступаю с кодом java, но в нем я хотя бы больше понимаю и больше пишу кода сам. А пхп я вообще не знаю что отвечает за права записи файлов. Вообще я заливаю файлы на хостинг через тотал командер, там есть авторизация. Я попробую сам создать папку uploads  и посмотрю что получится. спасибо за помощь

Comment: Попробуйте еще полный путь прописать для директории загрузки $uploads_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';

Comment: Так у Вас нет папки uploads? =)  PHP сам не создаст, папку нужно или программно или вручную создать и назначить права, разрешив туда запись

Answer (score 0):

получилось) спасибо aldem67 за помощь. ошибка была вот в чем -  нужно было поставить пробел после точки - $uploads_dir. $uploadname

Comment: О_О, ошибка не в этом )) в PHP это абсолютно не важно. хоть 100 пробелов поставьте, это никак не влияет, причина в другом была. Может просто совпало с другими правками, но точно причина не в этом

Comment: ясно, я не знаток в php

Comment: может это скорее из-за $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']